# Take advantage of Django Migration to save some data

Tags: python, django, django-models

I noticed that when you run **Django Migration**, some data is added to table `auth_permission` when a new model is created. Is there any way you can take advantage of migration process to do the same with your own models? I red [Django Documentation about writing Migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/writing-migrations/), but it only covers the creation of brand new migration processes, it doesn't say anything about using the default one for your own porpoises.

Answer (score 2):

You can write `migrations.RunPython` like this

```
def insert_data(apps, schema_editor):
    YourModel = apps.get_model('<appname>', '<ModelName>')
    # now insert data with YourModel.

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('<appname>', '<dependency>'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(insert_data),
    ]
```

notice these:

- Model Loaded in migration hasn't implemented methods. for example is you customize save method, you must write that code here
- if you want to make migration reversible you must write a new function for reverse operation and add argument `reverse_code` to your `RunPython` line. you can use `migrations.RunPython.noop` to make reverse migration do nothing.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I implemented your suggestion, but I never get the code executed. I run **makemigrations** and **migrate**, but the code is never reached. What do I have to do for it to be executed? When is it supposed to be executed, when makingmigrations or when migrating?

Comment: this codes must be in migration folder of your app. no `makemigration` needed. you file name must be started with a four digit number in incremental order. and you must add dependency to previous migration in your application.

Comment: you can generate migration with command `python manage.py makemigration myapp --empty` then insert code into it

Comment: Ok, got it. It ended not been the right solution for my situation, but I am applying this method in other case. Thanks a lot @vorujack